# Trigger radio button changed on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this radio button which is selected when the page loads:

```
<input ng-init="model.PeriodType = 'Accounting Period'"
       name="accperiodradio"
       id="accperiod"
       type="radio"
       ng-model="model.PeriodType"
       value="Accounting Period" />
```

and this change event handler:

```
$scope.$watch('model.PeriodType', function (value) {
    if (value == 'Accounting Period') {
        //do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

The `$scope.$watch` function triggers when another radio button is selected and then Accounting Period radio button is selected, but it's not triggered when the page loads since it's selected by default.

How can I get the `$scope.$watch` function to execute when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`.

```
<input ̶n̶g̶-̶i̶n̶i̶t̶=̶"̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶.̶P̶e̶r̶i̶o̶d̶T̶y̶p̶e̶ ̶=̶ ̶'̶A̶c̶c̶o̶u̶n̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶P̶e̶r̶i̶o̶d̶'̶"̶
       name="accperiodradio"
       id="accperiod"
       type="radio"
       ng-model="model.PeriodType"
       value="Accounting Period" />
```

Instead initialize the model from the controller:

```
$scope.model.PeriodType = "Accounting Period";
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)